# horizontal line across screen at startup

Tags: plymouth

I recently ran an upgrade from 12.04 to 12.10 and was using Nvidia current tested drivers and all seemed ok at first. Then suddenly every time I started the computer and shutdown, the graphical plymouth logo changed to text.The only changes I made to try to correct this issue were;

sudo apt-get --purge remove nvidia-current nvidia-settings

sudo apt-get --purge autoremove

sudo apt-get clean

sudo apt-get update

sudo apt-get install nvidia-current

and this made no change at all to the display.

Then I read somewhere that Nouveau drivers may be the answer, so I installed them to use instead, and hey presto, the shutdown screen displays the Plymouth splash.

However with startup, I get a stable purple screen, for a while, and than a thick black horizontal line appears, really ugly-looking, and then the loging screen appears to be ok.

Can I correct the login screen same as the shutdown screen?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had similar but not identical problems during the 12.04 to 12.10 upgrade, and I had to remove all nVidia display drivers and then installing nvidia-experimental-304 and nvidia-settings-experimental-304 after which I got a working graphical environment display.

To achieve this, because my display was useless, I had to log in to a terminal screen rather than try to use the graphical login. Once it's booted to the crapped up display, press CTRL ALT F2 (or any F button except F7 which is where the crap display was) and log in, remove the nVidia stuff (I did it using sudo apt-get purge nvidia-current), reboot, log in to a command screen again and install the experimental 304 stuff, reboot and see what happens this time.

That's what worked for me. Hope it's good for you!

Comment: Ok so I've removed the Nvidia drivers I had installed. I want to follow the next step you suggested, so do I just instal the experimental 304 version with kernel I found in the software updater additional drivers or is there something else too I should be installing. By the way, I apologise for this late reply after you have kindly helped me with this problem.

Comment: WOW! You deserve a medal to my way of thinking. THis has solved my problem after days of searching for help on this subject. I did undinstall all the Nvidia drivers as mentioned above, Then resstarted the computer and found the experimental 304 version with kernel in Software Update > Settings, installed it, restarted the machine and hey presto, one beautiful ubuntu plymouth logo to be seen. Can't say others would say it's beautiful but it is too me when somethings's gone wrong with graphics. Thanks very much for your advice! Great work!

Comment: Hi Debbie. I am glad it worked, because I know that nVidia can be quite hard work at times, and your hardware will be different from mine. So if you're happy, then I'm happy! Maybe you could mark my answer as "useful"? Cheers

Answer (score 0):

Thanks,
worked for me...
In summary
sudo apt-get --purge remove nvidia-current nvidia-settings

sudo apt-get --purge autoremove

sudo apt-get clean

sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install nvidia-experimental-304

sudo apt-get install nvidia-settings-experimental-304